# Is it possible to retrieve the WHERE clause in a DELETE ON trigger in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a basic table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id     uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  value1 int NOT NULL,
  value2 int NOT NULL
);
```

And I create a trigger for this table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
  BEFORE DELETE ON my_table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_function();
```

If I execute the statement

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE value1 > 2 AND value2 <= 20;
```

is it possible to access the delete statement's conditions (i.e., `value1 > 2 AND value2 <= 20`) in `my_function`?

Comment: Try `select query into <text_variable> from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid();` inside the trigger function.

Comment: Also remember that the deletion can be implicitly called by the cascaded foreign keys or can be performed by `delete ... where current of <cursor>`.